# How can I install cuDNN on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to install cuDNN. But I can't get access to any cuDNN debian package from https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download. Each link to a Ubuntu deb package echos a 403 error and says "Page Not Found". I want to know is there another way to install cuDNN?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But what I want to install is cuDNN (not CUDA which I have already installed). And you are right, I should ask only for other ways of installing cuDNN.

Comment: When I open this page, I get a login prompt and HTTP code 403 means "Not authorized" instead of "Page Not Found" (error on the NVIDIA web server), so this might be a cookie/login issue.

Answer (score 8):

I tried to download the Library for Linux and it works.

[image]

The file downloaded is with a postfix `.solitairetheme8`. Just rename it with post fix `.ga.tgz`, and unarchive it with `tar -zxvf cudnn....`. Then copy the files:

```
cd cuda
sudo cp include/* /usr/cuda-8.0/include/
sudo cp lib64/* /usr/cuda-8.0/lib64/
```

And it is completed.

Comment: There you go :-)

Comment: Do you know why it is a solitairetheme8 file by any chance? It's really weird and worrying at the least. I feel like this could easily have been some malware or something that changed the file extension...

Comment: It seems that some kind of CMS softwares will change the extension name of archived files to "solitairetheme8". And this seems to happen on only several versions of several browsers (including MS-Edge, Chrome). So if something has changed the file extension, it is the CMS itself, I suppose. :-)